# Make Google Plus post through .NET (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, google-plus

Good day all.

Does anyone has a working example how to make Google Plus post through .NET (C#).

I have already tried google and stackoverflow search, but did not manage to find the solution.

I successfully get posts:

```
    public void Post(string text)
    {
        PlusService plus = new PlusService {Key = "MYVERYSECRETKEY"};

        ActivitiesResource ar = new ActivitiesResource(plus, null);

        ActivitiesResource.ListRequest list = ar.List("108055870103885325249", new ActivitiesResource.Collection());
        ActivityFeed feed = list.Fetch();

        string activityKey = "";
        foreach (var a in feed.Items)
            if (a.Url == "https://plus.google.com/108055870103885325249/posts/EtvvUgn8eKz")
            {
                activityKey = a.Id;
                break;
            }

        ActivitiesResource.GetRequest get = ar.Get(activityKey);
        Activity act = get.Fetch();
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.AppendLine("Title: " + act.Title);
        sb.AppendLine("URL:" + act.Url);
        sb.AppendLine("Published:" + act.Published);
        sb.AppendLine("By:" + act.Actor.DisplayName);
        sb.AppendLine("Annotation:" + act.Annotation);
        sb.AppendLine("Content:" + act.Object.Content);
        sb.AppendLine("Type:" + act.Object.ObjectType);
        sb.AppendLine("# of +1s:" + act.Object.Plusoners.TotalItems);
        sb.AppendLine("# of reshares:" + act.Object.Resharers.TotalItems);
    }
```

But I cannot find any method for making posts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you seen [this Google plus platform page](https://developers.google.com/+/downloads/)? It has a (beta as of now) [.net client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/) too

Comment: I use this lib but cannot find how to post using it

Comment: @user306080: Please show what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, the Google+ API does not allow writing of posts to a user's activity stream. You can use the [moments.insert method in the Google+ REST API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments) to write [App Activities](https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities) to the user's profile, which the user can choose whether to share publicly or to their circles.

You would work with the REST API in a similar manner to other REST APIs in .NET by POSTing to the [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) end-point.

This feature is now available to apps that request the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login` scope and specify the [type of moments](https://developers.google.com/+/api/moment-types) that the app wants to write in the  `request_visible_actions` parameter either in the [Google+ Sign-In button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/#button_attr_requestvisibleactions) or directly in the OAuth query parameters.