# How to share a track/any content from my radio/music application to google+?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, google-plus

I've referred this question, [Make Google Plus post through .NET (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12956251/make-google-plus-post-through-net-c][1]) but this question was asked a long back, so now, is it possible to share a content to google+ from my application? I didn't find anything from searching. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have the client secret, api key and google token.

Comment: try with ShareMediaTask as below.  ShareMediaTask shareMediaTask = new ShareMediaTask();
           shareMediaTask.FilePath = path;
           shareMediaTask.Show();

Comment: i need to make use of the google+ token and all.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833438/google-plus-integration-in-windows-phone-8-and-windows-8-store-app